# Demonstration of the Riccati Equation Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem:

Riccati's equation is given by $$y'= P(x)y^2 + Q(x)y + R(x)$$

**(a)** Show that if a solution of this equation is known, say $$y_{1}(x)$$  it is known, then the general solution can be found using the transformation $$y = y_{1} + 1/u$$ where **"u"**  is a new dependent variable.

**(b)** Show that if two solutions are known, say  $$y_{1}(x) , y_{2}(x)$$, the general solution is $$\frac{y-y_{1}}{y-y_{2}}=C*e^{\int P(y_{1}-y_{2})dx}$$

**(c)** Show that three solutions are known, say $$y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3}$$, then the general solution is $$\frac{(y-y_{1})(y_{2}-y_{3})}{(y-y_{2})(y_{1}-y_{3})}=C$$

I have managed to prove subsection (a), but the others do not know how to do it, I have investigated but I cannot find how to start.

Comment: b) Compute the derivative of the fraction on the left side, find a differential equation for it. c) Apply b) twice.